# Custom post type rewrite slug translate?

Tags: custom-post-types

I use

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'uniquename')
```

for custom post type, and I will have site in two languages. 
I tried to use

```
if( is_main_site() ) { $slug = 'uniquename' } else { $slug = 'uniquenametwo' }
```

and then enter it in rewrite value, but that didn't seem to work. 
What other options do I have?

Comment: PS
I use is_main_site to translate templates in my website with using multisite

Answer (score 0):

so I added

```
if( is_main_site()) { $slug = 'uniquename'; } else {  $slug = 'uniquenametwo'; }
```

and

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug ),
```

inside register_post_type function and it worked. before i tried outside it. Im new to this. 
Anyway this worked in my case.